# Using HttpResponseCache

Tags: android

I want to use `HttpResponseCache` in my app, I've installed it successfully and it writes the cached content but actually I don't know how to use it in `HttpURLConnection`. android documentation doesn't fully cover this aspect.

What I want to do is to cache responses for 12 hours and in that time period it just get data from cache and don't even connect to check if there is a new version (My data changes in 24 hour). When this time pass the cache must be bypassed and a connection for a new version of data get established. I think the default behavior is to always check for new version.

I found out that first `setUseCaches(true)` must be true. But I don't know how to set "Cache-Control" so it works. I searched every where but I couldn't find this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Just started to work with `HttpResponse` myself. I'm using this within an `AsyncTasks` to download an Image. I'm not sure if my implementation with the `HttpUrlConnection` is 100% correct, I added my thoughts in the code. please comment or correct if you can improve this!

```
  public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String link) {

        try {
            //open connection 
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();


            Bitmap myBitmap;
            try {
                //Add property, to check if HTTPRequest is saved in chache
                //if true: continue
                //if false: FileNotFoundException (see catch block) 
                connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control",
                        "only-if-cached");

                InputStream cached = connection.getInputStream();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cached);

                Log.i(TAG,"Image was saved in CHACHE!!!");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                //because I tried to read the input stream in the try block, I have to establish again
                //!!! NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT!?

                HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection2.setDoInput(true);

                //set max stale in seconds (this should be saved in cache for one hour (60seconds * 60 minutes)!)
                connection2.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + (60 * 60));
                connection2.connect();
                InputStream input = connection2.getInputStream();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                Log.i(TAG,"Image was NOT CACHED!!");
            }

            return myBitmap;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("getBmpFromUrl error: ", e.getMessage().toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```